# Bootstrap 3 Customizations: Tweak, Test, Rinse & Repeat

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to customize Bootstrap 3 and have perused [the main BS customization page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

A few questions:

1. Right in the center of that page is the following text: "*Have an existing configuration? Upload your `config.json` to import it.*". **What is config.json?** I don't see any `config.json` files in the version of Bootstrap that I just downloaded...
2. This page has a nifty little form where I can muck around with LESS variables, and then generate a custom bootstrap that uses those variables. Clicking the "*Compile and Download*" button at the bottom of this form generates a `bootstrap.zip`. However this tool doesn't give me any way to sample the variable values inside any kind of "showcase" app. So I ask: **how can I take the `bootstrap.zip` this generates and apply my custom version of Bootstrap to *something* (anything) that will demo my custom look-and-feel? I've heard that the Bootstrap docs might be a good source for this sort of "showcase app", but not sure how to obtain those locally on my machine, or how to apply my custom styles to them.

Comment: For your second question, the Bootswatch template site at http://bootswatch.com might give you a good way to try out your theme. It should be pretty easy to plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. config.json is used when you change the variables, if you don't change anything it won't be generated.

[image]

2. go to bootstrap repo and download the master.zip -- the docs are there.

[image]

3. Google for Bootstrap 3 Kitchen Sink, you can likely find an html file to use to test out your theme. I recently made this: http://jsbin.com/homec/1/ - go to the edit file: http://jsbin.com/homec/1/edit?html,css,js,output and then remove the link to the CDN and add a link to your file on your server OR just copy out the html and fiddle with it locally.
4. It's easier to use LESS directly and then view your site as it gets updated locally. CodeKit does this for me and it's very fast.
5. As with any Kitchen Sink html you find double check it against the docs and make sure it's been implemented correctly. Always read the docs and use their examples as a starting point.